# Equation to distribute items unevenly

Tags: math, distribution, logarithm, exponential, exponent

I'm writing a javascript program that sends a list of MIDI signals over a specified period of time.

If the signals are sent evenly, it's easy to determine how long to wait in between each signal: it's just the total duration divided by the number of signals.

However, I want to be able to offer a setting where the signals aren't sent equally: either the signals are sent with increasing or decreasing speed. In either case, the number of signals and the total amount of time remain the same.

[Here's a picture to visualize what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMZAj.jpg)

Is there a simple logarithmic/exponential function where I can compute what these values are? I'm especially hoping it might be possible to use the same equation for both, simply changing a variable.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not give any method to get a pulse value, from the previous value or any other way, I assume we are free to come up with our own.

In both of your cases, it looks like you start with an initial time interval: let's call it a. Then the next interval is that value multiplied by a constant ratio: let's call it r. In the first decreasing case, your value of r is between zero and one (it looks like around 0.6), while in the second case your value of r is greater than one (around 1.6). So your time intervals, in Python notation, are

```
a, a*r, a*r**2, a*r**3, ...
```

Then the time of each signal is the [sum of a geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum),

```
a * (1 - r**n) / (1 - r)
```

where n is the number of the pulse (1 for the first, 2 for the second, etc.). That formula is valid if r is not one, but if r is one then the sequence is a trivial sequence of a regular signal and the nth signal is given at time

```
a * n
```

This is not a "fixed result" since you have two degrees of freedom--you can choose values of a and of r.

If you want to spread the signals more evenly, just bring r closer to one. A value of one is perfectly even, a value farther from one is more clumped at one end. One disadvantage of this method is that if the signal intervals are decreasing then the signals will completely stop at some point, namely at

```
a / (1 - r)
```

If you have signals already sent or received and you want to find the value of r, just find the time interval between three consecutive signals, and r is the value of the time interval between the 2nd and 3rd signal divided by the time interview between the 1st and 2nd signal. If you want to see if this model is a good one for a given set of signals, check the value of r at multiple signals--if the value of r is nearly constant then this is a good model.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think I understand what you're suggesting. Just to clarify: the image in the OP isn't to scale – I just plotted a few points on a graph to show what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish. Based on your answer, two questions: 1) How do I find the constant ratio "r", and 2) this seems to provide a fixed result. What would I change to allow this signals to be more equally distributed, or less equally distributed? r?

Comment: @Matthew: See the additions to my answer.